# Manipulating dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I have a dictionary that stores months:

```
Months = {'January': 1, 'February': 2, 'March': 3, 'April': 4, 'May': 5, 'June': 6, 'July': 7, 'August': 8, 'September': 9, 'October': 10, 'November': 11, 'December': 12
```

And I have a while loop, that loops 12 times (one year):

(pseudo)

```
Month = 1
Final = 12
while Month <= Final:
    call Month_from_dictionary_as_string_here
    Month += 1
```

how can I call dictionary keys depending on the value of the other variable? Thanks.

Comment: You have the dictionary the wrong way around...

Comment: You can't, dictionaries aren't meant to be used that way

Answer (score 2):

I you are meant on using `while` loop(`while` loop is seldom used for iteration in python), then you need a reverse hash or dictionary for this purpose

```
reverse_months = {value: key for key, value in Months.items()}

print(reverse_months[1]) # January
```

A better implementation would be using `for` loop -

```
for month in range(1, 13):
    print(reverse_months[month])
```

Although, why do you need `looping` at all in first place, I guess you can easily make do with an iterator, unless your use case is much different from what your code suggests.

```
for key, value in Months.items():
    print("key: {0}, value: {1}".format(key, value)
```

P.S. - Please go through [Pep 8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) too for naming conventions in python

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you have the dictionary backwards. You should map from numbers (`key`) to names of month (`value`) . Example -

```
months_dict = {1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May', 6: 'June', 7: 'July', 8: 'August', 9: 'September', 10: 'October', 11: 'November', 12: 'December'}
```

Then you can directly use subscript to get the name of the month using the number -

```
months_dict = {1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May', 6: 'June', 7: 'July', 8: 'August', 9: 'September', 10: 'October', 11: 'November', 12: 'December'}
for i in range(1,13):
    print(months_dict[i])
```

while loop version, if for some reason you do not want to use `for` loop (which is what you should normally use for this) -

```
month = 1
while month <= 12:
    print(months_dict[i])
    month += 1
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Months = {'January': 1, 'February': 2, 'March': 3, 'April': 4, 'May': 5, 'June': 6, 'July': 7, 'August': 8, 'September': 9, 'October': 10, 'November': 11, 'December': 12}

Month = 1
Final = 12
while Month <= Final:
    for mon, digit in Months.items():
        if Month == digit:
            print (mon)  # in your case call Month_from_dictionary_as_string_here
    Month += 1
```

Comment: That's a very inefficient way to use a dictionary, particularly as you don't even `break` when it's found. Also, it's good to include some explanation as to why your changes work.